# Map and pushing arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am quite new to React and TypeScript. I have some icons I want to map like this:

```
const iconLookups =
    dataPackNumber1.map(
      (e) =>
        e.icon_prefix &&
        e.icon_name && {
          prefix: e.icon_prefix,
          iconName: e.icon_name,
        },
    ) as IconLookup[];
```

Further I have more icons under `dataPackNumber2` and `dataPackNumber3` that look the same and I would like to map them all at once. Another way I was thinking of was to map them seperately and then to push them into the `iconLookups` array, but I cant seem to figure out how.

```
iconLookups.push(
    dataPackNumber.map(
      (e) =>
        e.icon_prefix &&
        e.icon_name && {
          prefix: e.icon_prefix,
          iconName: e.icon_name,
        },
    ) as IconLookup[];)
```

and

```
const iconLookups =
    dataPackNumber1 && dataPackNumber2 && dataPackNumber3.map(
      (e) =>
        e.icon_prefix &&
        e.icon_name && {
          prefix: e.icon_prefix,
          iconName: e.icon_name,
        },
    ) as IconLookup[];
```

The code doesn't provide me errors, but on the UI I can see that only the last provided `dataPackNumber` will be actually rendered, if I chain them with `&&`.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Stack overflow protip: "Doesn't work" is not a valid phrase in the English language as far as SO is concerned, less meaningful than *Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah-nagl fhtagn*. What **exact** behavior are you seeing? What are you expecting to see? Your logic uses short-circuiting AND, does the type `IconLookup` include undefined?

Comment: [ask] -> [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.push()` will push *one element* onto the array.  In your case, that element is an entire array.  Resulting in a structure like this:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]
```

`&&` will likely just resolve to the last expression, which in your case is just `dataPackNumber3.map(/*...*/)`.

One way to combine all three is with the spread syntax.  Structurally it would be something like:

```
let result = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3];
```

So in your case it might be:

```
const iconLookups = [
  ...dataPackNumber1,
  ...dataPackNumber2,
  ...dataPackNumber3.map(/*...*/)
] as IconLookup[];
```

---

**Edit:** As pointed out [in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882487/map-and-pushing-arrays/73882593?noredirect=1#comment130457332_73882593), `.push()` *can* indeed add multiple elements to an array when added as multiple arguments:

```
arr1.push(3, 4, 5);
```

Which means the spread syntax can also work there:

```
const iconLookups = dataPackNumber1.map(/*...*/) as IconLookup[];
iconLookups.push(...dataPackNumber2.map(/*...*/));
iconLookups.push(...dataPackNumber3.map(/*...*/));
```

Comment: `push` can push multiple elements, `push(1, 2, 3)` for example. So it could work with spread: `push(...myArray)`

Comment: @caTS: I guess I've learned something new today.  The spread syntax appears to work there as well.  Updating the answer...

Comment: @David Your first example is only mapping dataPackNumber3

Comment: @Vinicius: So is the example in the question (one of them, anyway): `dataPackNumber1 && dataPackNumber2 && dataPackNumber3.map()`  Whether its the original array or a new array returned by `.map()`, the structure is the same.

Comment: @David Sure, but I think the OP put the map only at the last array by mistake. He wrote "I have more icons under dataPackNumber2 and dataPackNumber3 that look the same" and logically the final structure must be homogeneous.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve it thanks to you :) The spread syntax did the trick.